# Get table alias names to appear as part of the column names in query results

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

In Postgres, a query like this:

`SELECT a.id, b.id FROM table1 a INNER JOIN table2 b on a.id=b.id;`

Will return 'deconflicted' column names like:

> a.id, b.id

However, in Oracle, the `id` columns just keep their original names:

> id, id

My problem here is that my follow-on tools are confused by the duplicate column names.

In this example, I've only listed 2 columns, but in reality there are 100's, and I'd prefer to not have to list them all out.

Is there a way to do this without having to specify all of the column names (there are 100's).

Comment: You could use Oracle Data Cartridge to create a function that accepts any SQL statement and modifies the column names.  Then each SQL statement would have to be run through that function, like `select * from table(change_column_names('select a.id, b.id ...'));`.  If that is good enough I could create a modified version of [this project file](https://github.com/method5/method4/blob/master/method4_dynamic_ot.tpb).  Specifically in lines 77 to 93, the loop could check for duplicates and rename them before the query is "described".  Let me know if that's worth building.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there won't be because table names (or aliases) aren't a requirement.
For example the following is valid SQL for Oracle, but there's no viable prefix to include in column naming.

```
SELECT * FROM 
   (select 1 a, 2 b from dual) 
  join 
   (select 1 a, 3 b from dual) 
  using (a)
```

But I think Postgres requires those FROM subqueries to be aliased

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.id as 'table1 a', b.id as 'table2 b' FROM table1 a INNER JOIN table2 b on a.id=b.id group by a.id, b.id;
```

You can name your results with `as` followed by the name. If you want to use `JOIN`, you have to use `GROUP BY` followed by your selected items if you don't want duplicate values.

Comment: Sure, I'm familiar with this approach.   But let me highlight the last sentence:  "Is there a way to do this without having to specify all of the column names (there are 100's).

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the particular problem with `id` by fixing the `join`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 a INNER JOIN
     table2 b 
     USING (id);
```

If `id` is the only duplicate column, then this may solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, but I have 100's of columns, see the last sentence.